# Can someone tell me Rally CA agile central default severity and priority levels for bugs ? Can it be changed?

Tags: rally

Can you list me the different levels of Severity and Priority that are on Rally CA agile central?

Answer (score 2):

According to this help page they can be customized by a subscription adminstrator: https://help.rallydev.com/defects

By default Priority has these values:

```
1 - Resolve Immediately
2 - High Attention
3 - Normal
4 - Low
```

By default Severity has these values:

```
1 - Crash/Data Loss
2 - Major Problem
3 - Minor Problem
4 - Cosmetic
```